# One back-propagation pass in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, backpropagation, policy-gradient-descent

I  would like to train a neural network based on policy gradient method. The training involves finding the gradient of a user-defined loss (one back-propagation pass). I know gradient is automatically done during compiling as follows

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

However, this code does multiple forward and back passes through the NN. What I am looking for is a single back-propagation. My question is whether it is possible to do one back-propagation pass in keras or I need to do it in Pytorch or tensorflow.

Comment: No, this code does not do any backpropagation, only fit would perform backpropagation, maybe you are looking into train_on _batch?

Comment: Or to me it now sounds like you want to compute gradients? (that is the only thing that backpropagation does)

Comment: You are right Dr.Snoopy. The gradient is done by model.fit . Yes I want to do a one-time back-propagation (gradient)

Comment: Computing gradients in keras has been asked many many times, did you search this site?

Comment: @mohamed I think it can be done by both keras or pytorch. . Can you provide some starter where you've tried to achieve what you're looking for?